# Hodge decomposition on a manifold with a nontrivial connection

Tags: manifolds, differential-forms, hodge-theory

I am familiar with the notion of Hodge decomposition of an arbitrary differential form into an exact form, a co-exact form, and a harmonic form. Given a curved space with a connection, could you extend the concept of Hodge decomposition by promoting the exterior derivative and codifferential to their covariant counterparts?

Comment: Have you figured this out since the question was asked?

Comment: Not really--at least not within Cartan's framework. The more I read about these subjects, the more I suspect David Hestenes's Geometric Calculus is an easier framework for me. If I come across an answer, I will be sure to post it.